# Multiple CSS content for markup with multiple classes

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am trying to add icons with CSS *content* value to different classes. Some markup might have multiple classes, in which case I want multiple icons after the text. Problem is, I am not sure if I can add multiple *content* values to the same class.

Example:

```css
.entry-header::after {font-family: FontAwesome; font-size: 15px; /*float: right;*/}

.status-private > .entry-header::after {
    content: " \f023"
}
.format-standard > .entry-header::after {
    content: " \f040"
}
.format-video > .entry-header::after {
    content: " \f03d"
}
```

In the case where a class is e.g. `.status-private` a logo will be displayed, but what if the markup has **two** classes? Such as `.status-private .format-standard`? How can I then display two icons?

If possible, I would avoid having to make CSS for every possible combination of these three classes.

My current markup:

```
<article id="post-1713" class="post-1713 post type-post status-private format-video hentry category-uncategorized post_format-post-format-video">
    <header class="entry-header">

        <div class="entry-date">
            May 20, 2016
        </div>

        <div class="entry-title post-1713 post type-post status-private format-video hentry category-uncategorized post_format-post-format-video">
            Private: Private: This is a video post
        </div>

    </header><!-- .entry-header -->

    <div class="entry-content" data-did-load="true" style="display: none;">
        <p>
            The format of this post is video, but the video has not yet been added
        </p>
    </div><!-- .entry-content -->
</article>
```

I want to display the icons after *Private: This is a video post*

Comment: please show your html code

Comment: If you want to show *different* content when there are *two* classes, you will have to specify that with new selectors, unfortunately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot have multiple pseudo elements on the same element. Even if you could, as mentioned in original answer, just having `::after::after` will not help you avoid duplication.

This is where I'd prefer practicality over purity. I'd just add an empty `span` for each status with each of the CSS `class`es, and target these in the CSS still with `::after` etc.

**Update 1: Example:**

```css
.entry-header > .icon::after {font-family: FontAwesome; font-size: 15px; /*float: right;*/}

.entry-header > .icon-status-private::after {
    content: " \f023"
}

.entry-header > .icon-format-standard::after {
    content: " \f040"
}
.entry-header > .icon-format-video::after {
    content: " \f03d"
}
```

```html
<!-- To show icons -->
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div class="status-private">
  <div class="entry-header">
    <span class="icon icon-status-private"></span>
    Private
  </div>
</div>

<div class="status-private">
  <div class="entry-header">
    <span class="icon icon-status-private"></span>
    <span class="icon icon-format-standard"></span>
    Private Article
  </div>
</div>

<div class="status-private">
  <div class="entry-header">
    <span class="icon icon-status-private"></span>
    <span class="icon icon-format-standard"></span>
    <span class="icon icon-format-video"></span>
    Private Video Article
  </div>
</div>
```

> Note: You can change the `.icon` in the first CSS line to `[class=*'icon-']`, and remove the redundant `icon` class from the `span`s.

If you are using some programming language (Serverside or JavaScript), you can use some programming checks to decide to write each `span` in the HTML.

**Update 2: Avoiding HTML Changes**

If you really have to keep the HTML as-is. You'll have to duplicate the selectors I'm afraid.

In your particular situation, it's not too bad actually. Here's the full example from your updated question HTML:

```css
.entry-header::after {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-size: 15px; 
  float: right;
}

.format-standard > .entry-header::after {
    content: " \f040";
}
.status-private.format-standard > .entry-header::after {
    /*Had to put 2 spaces to make the icons separate */
    content: " \f023  \f040";
}

.format-video > .entry-header::after {
    content: " \f03d";
}
.status-private.format-video > .entry-header::after {
    /*Had to put 2 spaces to make the icons separate */
    content: " \f023  \f03d";
}

/* Might not be needed now */
.status-private > .entry-header::after {
    content: " \f023";
}
```

```html
<!-- To show icons -->
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<article id="post-1713" class="post-1713 post type-post status-private format-video hentry category-uncategorized post_format-post-format-video">
    <header class="entry-header">

        <div class="entry-date">
            May 20, 2016
        </div>

        <div class="entry-title post-1713 post type-post status-private format-video hentry category-uncategorized post_format-post-format-video">
            Private: Private: This is a video post
        </div>

    </header><!-- .entry-header -->

    <div class="entry-content" data-did-load="true" style="display: none;">
        <p>
            The format of this post is video, but the video has not yet been added
        </p>
    </div><!-- .entry-content -->
</article>
```

Comment: I think I get what you mean. But I am a little green on this.. sorry. Could you do an example please?

Comment: I added one to the question now. This approach is a bit involved (it requires changing the HTML), but it's either that, or repeating the selectors (which isn't too much to be honest in your case).

Comment: Thanks. I tried to work on what you gave me. But since I have different markup I got lost pretty quick. I also could not find out how to add one `span` for each post format in Wordpress. Could you please update your example to reflect on my markup if it is possible? I would be forever grateful if you did. Thanks again!

Comment: No problem. I added a big updated to the beginning of the question, and an example using your HTML to the end of the question. Short version is: you can't avoid duplication, but it's not too bad in this particular case.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the effort! You have really done a great job here!

Answer (score 0):

Can Add multiple content like this too.

```css
div::after{
  font-family: FontAwesome;
}
.icon::after{
  content: "\f03d";
  font-size: 30px;
}
.icon.icon2::after{
  content: "\f023  \f03d  \f023";
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">  
</head>

<div class="icon"></div>
<div class="icon icon2"></div>
```

Comment: The question says that the element might have 1, 2 or 3 of different classes, based on which classes it has, it might have 1, 2 or 3 of the `content` values. The OP does NOT want to write different selectors for each 2-class combinations and the 3 classes combinations either. How does this answer solve this?

Comment: "Some markup might have multiple classes, in which case I want multiple icons after the text. Problem is, I am not sure if I can add multiple content values to the same class."

"In the case where a class is e.g. .status-private a logo will be displayed, but what if the markup has two classes? Such as .status-private .format-standard? How can I then display two icons?"

Comment: He says, want to add more content depending on classes. He may be want to add two icons for class .status-private.format-standard. So, my exmaple has .icon.icon2 with two values. Maybe I'm reading another question, but as I read THIS ONE, he needs to add more than one value on "content".

Comment: Quoting the last line in the question, literally: "If possible, I would avoid having to make CSS for every possible combination of these three classes."

Comment: Besides, the original comment was written about the answer before your edit, when you had the `icons` instead of `.icon.icon2` now. It still does not address the quoted part after the edit though.